# how to loop array from given array in php

Tags: php

I've array like this in php I want to loop this array inside div elements in php:

```
`Array
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => Masaladosa
            [1] => Zingafry
            [2] => Idli
            [3] => Tandoori Baby Corn Mushroom
            [4] => Bharwan Aloo
        )
    [qty] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
        )
    [price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 320
            [1] => 800
            [2] => 70
            [3] => 560
            [4] => 560
       )
)`
```

I want to use loop this array inside following div:

```
<div class="row mt-4 mx-1">
    <div class="col-6 text-start item-listmenu">
    <p class="bill-order">Masala dosa</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 text-start">
        <p class="bill-order">2</p>
        </div>
    <div class="col-4 text-end">
    <p class="bill-order"><span>&#8377;</span>320</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

and so on.

Comment: foreach loop over one of the sub-arrays, and then use the key to access the corresponding elements out of the other two.

Comment: I hope that data are comng from a your own code, in this case the structure is wrong, not scalable and you can have errors on it, reform your data to have something like $data([itemName => [price = x.xx],[qty = y]],[item2NAme.... in this way you can add attributes and scale up without problems in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution: Split the array into three (one for Item, Qty, and Price), and use a foreach with a named index variable. This works as long as the numerical index is consistent across all three nested arrays:

```
<?php

$itemArray = $array['item'];
$qtyArray = $array['qty'];
$priceArray = $array['price'];

foreach($itemArray as $key => $item) {
    var_dump($item, $qtyArray[$key], $priceArray[$key]); // Note that $item === $itemArray[$key]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't an answer per se but I don't know how in a comment to write the layout of the array.
And so, all that to say that the **organization of your data** in arrays is **very strange**.
 Can't you have a array of this type instead...?
 It would be much more consistent and easier to navigate to view the layers.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => Masaladosa
            [qty] => 2
            [price] => 320
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => Zingafry
            [qty] => 4
            [price] => 800
        )

)
```

...

```
// An example to browse this array (nammed list)
foreach($list as $key => $val)
{
    echo "<br />".$key." - ".$val["item"]." - ".$val["qty"]." - ".$val["price"];
}
```